# Python os.system(python "program") not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, libraries

I'm writing a program with multiple pieces of code, and don't want someone to have to manually copy-paste the entire directory from an install disk, so I've written something that will do it for them (like an autorun).

However, when I try to launch the program after copying it over to the user's computer, I get:

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

instead of the installer booting the program.

This is the def I'm using:

```
import os

get_project_base_directory()
    check_version()
    print jason_dir
    new_dir = str(jason_dir+"/Jason_Core/Boot.py")
    command = "python " + new_dir
    print command
    os.system(command)
```

Why might os.system might not be working? I've also tried popopen and subprocess, but the had the same output (exit code 0).

**EDIT:** I am running this in a script, not the python command line.

**EDIT 2:** As requested, Boot.py:

```
# 3rd party libraries
import os
import subprocess
import shutil
from imp import find_module


# My code to import


basedir = ""

# Get the project base directory (drive located on)
def get_project_base_directory():
    global basedir
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    basedir = "/".join(cwd.split("\\")[:len(cwd.split("\\"))-1])
    #print basedir


# Copies libraries from disk drive
def copy_libs():
    new_dir = "c:/Downloads/Python_Libraries"
    if os.path.exists(new_dir):
        shutil.rmtree(new_dir)
    old_dir = basedir + "/Libraries/Installed"
    #print old_dir
    try:
        shutil.copytree(old_dir, new_dir)
    except:
        print "     Error copying directories! Try manual copy."
        print "     Go to:", basedir + "/Libraries/Installed"


# Checks to see if the library is installed
def check_lib_install():
    temp_var = True
    libs_list = ("fbchat", "gtts", "pyaudio", "googlevoice", "espeak", "pywapi", "speech_recognition", "win10toast") # names of libs
    for lib in libs_list:
        print "Checking lib installation:", lib
        try:
            __import__(lib)
            print "     Lib installed"
            print ""
        except:
            print "     Lib not installed"
            install_lib(lib, libs_list.index(lib))
    print "All libraires installed!"


# Install libraries if they don't exist on this machine.
def install_lib(lib, index):
    print "     Installing lib:", lib
    libs_file_list = ("/fbchat-1.0.19/", "/gTTS-1.2.2/", "/PyAudio-0.2.11/", "/pygooglevoice-master/", "/python-espeak-0.5/", "/pywapi-0.3.8/", "/speech_recognition-master/", "/Windows-10-Toast-Notifications-master/")  # path to file
    print "Installing:", lib
    new_dir = "c:/Downloads/Python_Libraries" + libs_file_list[index]
    os.chdir(new_dir)
    try:
        temp_command = "python setup.py install"
        subprocess.call(temp_command)
    except:
        print lib, "failed installation. Try manual install."
    print ""


# Gets version number of local copy of Jason, and then the version number of the one on the disk drive. If the local version is lower, the python files are overwritten. If it doesn't yet exist locally, Jason is installed.
def check_version():
    local_version = "0"
    jason_dir = "C:/Jason_AI" # Where is jason installed to?
    if os.path.exists(jason_dir):
        with open(jason_dir+"\System Files\Version Number.txt") as local_jason:  # Where is jason installed to?
            counter = 0
            for line in local_jason:
                counter += 1
                if counter == 2:
                    local_version = line
                    #print local_version
                elif counter == 3:
                    break
        install_version_file = basedir + "\System Files\Version Number.txt"
        install_version_file = "/".join(install_version_file.split("\\"))
        with open(install_version_file) as drive_jason:
            counter = 0
            for line in drive_jason:
                counter += 1
                if counter == 2:
                    install_version = line
                    #print install_version
                    if install_version == local_version:
                        print "Version up to date!"
                        print "Using version number:", local_version
                    else:
                        shutil.rmtree(jason_dir)
                        print "Version outdated"
                        print "Using version number:", local_version
                elif counter == 3:
                    break
    else:
        print "Version outdated"
        print "Using version number:", local_version


# Controls the boot process, when done, launches into Listen.get_audio()
def control():
    get_project_base_directory()
    copy_libs()
    check_lib_install()
    import System_Logins # Importing this here since the required libraries might not be installed if its the first time running Jason on this machine
    import Actions  # ^^
    import System_Commands # ^^
    import Listen # ^^
    check_version()
    logins = System_Logins.read_logins(basedir)
    System_Commands.clear_screen()
    while True:
        speech = Listen.get_audio()
        Actions.sort(speech, logins)


def check_packages():
    packages = ["System_Logins", "Actions", "System_Commands", "Listen"]
    for package in packages:
        try:
            __import__(package) #Need to work on
            print package + ":", "successfully loaded."
            packages[packages.index(package)] = "True"
        except ImportError:
            print package + ":", "error."
    return packages


#Remote login (ie, from install)
def remote_control():
    packages = check_packages()
    #print packages
    if any(word in ("System_Logins", "Actions", "System_Commands", "Listen") for word in packages):
        control()
    import System_Logins  # Importing this here since the required libraries might not be installed if its the first time running Jason on this machine
    import Actions  # ^^
    import System_Commands  # ^^
    import Listen  # ^^
    logins = System_Logins.read_logins(basedir)
    System_Commands.clear_screen()
    while True:
        speech = Listen.get_audio()
        Actions.sort(speech, logins)


remote_control()
```

Comment: Are you calling the function in the script you're opening in python commandline? (the Boot.py)

Comment: @MattWBP I'm calling it in a script, not in python commandline

Comment: show the content of `Boot.py`

Comment: When you call os.system() you're running it as a commandline/system process. os.system(python pyscript.py) means run pyscript in python - so my question is, does the pyscript you're using include a line to call the functions within it. Perhaps if you include the contents of Boot.py in your question, it will help troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: @eyllanesc Boot.py added.

Comment: Python is able to retrieve code from a zip-style archive file. Much saner to leverage capabilities the interpreter already has than to try to build your own one-off hackery.

Comment: (Python *also* has tools for automatic installation and management -- see https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/ -- and/or an available 3rd-party ecosystem with tools like [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/), which could be used to bundle your program into a single executable that doesn't even need a separate Python interpreter).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I didn't know about pyinstaller! However, this actually works quite well, minus the `os.system(command)` not working. If I run Boot.py by itself, the whole program works (or what I have coded of it so far).

Comment: I don't know what you expect `os.system()` to *do*, so I've yet to be convinced that it isn't working as designed and specified. At the same time, though, using it is pretty much *always* a bad idea (true of pretty much any interface that parses both code and data out of the same string, running your code from an arbitrarily-named directory could run all manner of mischief), so this isn't an issue I'm much inclined to try to solve.

Comment: Speaking for myself, if you want my help, a [mcve] would be a place to start -- the *shortest possible self-contained code* that will reproduce your specific issue with `os.system()` -- ideally in a form that can just be copied-and-pasted into a REPL. Right now, there's nothing about this that's short *or* self-contained.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy if I just copy remote_control() its own file, `os.system(command)` and `subprocess.call(command)` (where command is the new file) works. I then decided to see if calling the old command works, and low-and-behold, it does. IDK why. Thanks for the suggestion of trimming down, and seeing if the problem arises!

Comment: (aside: it's "[lo and behold](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lo_and_behold)").